# Stm32F103C8T8 - error when I erase flash

Tags: flash, stm32

i using flash to save data, but sometime error happen when Erasing Flash, i don't understand why?

Thank for your help! sorry for my terible english

my program size: 30,46 kbyte.

Here is my function:

```
#define FLASH_PAGE_ADDR   0x08010000

uint16_t Mydata = 2345;

void WriteData(void)
{
    FLASH_Unlock(); 
    FLASH_ClearFlag(FLASH_FLAG_BSY | FLASH_FLAG_EOP | FLASH_FLAG_PGERR\
    |FLASH_FLAG_WRPRTERR);
    FLASH_ErasePage(FLASH_PAGE_ADDR);
    FLASH_ProgramHalfWord(FLASH_PAGE_ADDR+2, Mydata);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You chip has 64kB of flash memory, so trying to erase a page that does not exist (starting 64kB after start of flash) is not the best idea. Trying to do that may as well erase the *FIRST* page of flash, removing interrupt vectors and part of the running application.

Answer (score -1):

The device stm32F103C8T8 contains 64Kb of flash.

[image: Ordering information scheme]

And the memory layout looks like this:

[image: Memory map]

For your device the flash memory will actually be **0x08000000-0x0800FFFF** since you got the 64Kb variant. This memory will be our first *page* (aka *sector*) of flash memory. There are 64 pages for your device each being 1Kb in size. You can only erase full pages. See below picture for flash module organization:

[image: flash module organization]

In your example you tell the device to start erasing from **0x08010000**. With the information given above, this is of course not possible (since there is no memory at this location). I suggest you change the location so that it will target a valid page (staring at the beginning of a page):

```
#define FLASH_PAGE_4_ADDR   0x08001000
```

Make sure that you are  not executing from that very spot when erasing, since then, of course, your program will crash.

Also, consider looking at the return value from your functions that you use to erase with. They could tell you something important.

Comment: There are more pages in this chip than 1 - 64 actually, each 1kB in size. Also the advice to erase the beginning of flash is very nice indeed - a good idea if you want to crash your program immediately.

Comment: thank you so much ! i don't notice that flash size = 64kbyte

Comment: i want to ask more one question,i have that error sometime, so why can writedata funtion operate correctly if FLASH_PAGE_ADDR is out of space? why the error does not always happen

Comment: It is very strange If you get success as return value from the erase function when trying to erase non-existing address space. I think this is a question for ST Microelectronics and their HAL libraries.